# Unable to display modal on click of link

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to open a modal on click of a link. however, its not opening. Below is the code for the link:

```
<div class="span4" style="font-size: 14px">             
   <a href="#" onClick="openModal(); return false;" cssClass="view-more" >Some<br>textlater</a>
</div>
```

This is the code for the modal

```
   <div class="modal hide fade" id="myDiv" style="width: 520px;display: block;border: 1px solid black">
 <div class="modal-header" style="width: 517px;"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button></div>    
 <div class="modal-body"">
 <div id="mydiv1" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="span9"><img alt="img" style="margin-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 2px" src="./images/img.png"></div>
</div>    
</div> 
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="button-bar-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <s:a href="#" cssClass="btn btn-link btn-back" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span><s:text name="generic.cancel" /></span>
                </s:a>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                                  
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This is the function

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal(){
       alert("hello");
       $('myDiv').modal('show');
    }
```

PLease guide where am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.I was missing # before calling show modal. Below is the modified code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function openModal(){
      alert("hello");
   $('#myDiv').modal('show');
 }
```